# Backbonejs running Mocha tests (reporter html) hanging when run from the comandline

Tags: testing, backbone.js, jenkins, requirejs, mocha.js

We are writing a Backbone.js based app and trying to use our Mocha test with our Jenkins
Continuous Integration server.

So far I can run the tests using something like [Testem](https://github.com/airportyh/testem) or [mocha-phantomjs](https://github.com/metaskills/mocha-phantomjs). The test run but they never fire an exit code, and there fore the scripts never return to the command line prompt. This is exactly what the scripts are supposed to do so I am guessing that something is wrong with how we have set up our Mocha test library. I have not found the problem myself.

Has any one else run in to this problem and at least found a workaround.

Any ideas?

our test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dashboard Mocha Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mocha.css" />

  <script src="js/vendor/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    requirejs.config({
      baseUrl: 'js/',
      paths: {
        jquery        : 'vendor/jquery.min',
        underscore    : 'vendor/underscore',
        backbone      : 'vendor/backbone',
        handlebars    : 'vendor/handlebars',
        text          : 'vendor/require-text',
        json          : 'vendor/require-json',
        chaplin       : 'vendor/chaplin',
        mocha         : 'vendor/mocha',
        chai          : 'vendor/chai',
        sinon         : 'vendor/sinon',
        moment        : 'vendor/moment'
      },
      shim: {
        backbone: {
          deps        : ['underscore', 'jquery'],
          exports     : 'Backbone'
        },
        underscore: {
          exports     : '_'
        }
      }
    });

  if (location.hash === '#testem')
    document.write('<script src="/testem.js"></'+'script>')
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mocha"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    require(['require', 'vendor/chai', 'vendor/mocha', 'vendor/sinon'], function(require, chai) {

      assert = chai.assert;
      expect = chai.expect;
      should = chai.should();

      mocha.setup({
        ui: 'bdd',
      });
      var specs = [
        'test/lib/utils',
        'test/models/campaigns',
        'test/models/campaign',
        'test/views/input/input',
        'test/views/input/text',
        'test/views/input/textarea',
        'test/views/input/checkbox',
        'test/views/input/email',
        'test/views/input/password',
        'test/views/input/button',
        'test/views/input/submit_button',
        'test/views/input/reset_button',
        'test/views/input/number',
        'test/views/input/date_time',
        'test/views/input/date'
      ];
      require(specs, function() {
         mocha.run()
      })
    })
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is an example of how one of our test look.

```
(function() {

  define(['views/forms/textarea'], function(Textarea) {
    'use strict';
    return describe('Textarea', function() {
      var field;
      field = new Textarea;
      describe('defaults', function() {
        it('is enabled by default', function() {
          return assert.isTrue(field.isEnabled());
        });
        return it('contains one textarea field', function() {
          return assert.lengthOf($(field.el).find('textarea'), 1);
        });
      });
      return describe('value', function() {
        return it('can have set and get a value', function() {
          field.setValue('my super value');
          return assert.equal('my super value', field.getValue());
        });
      });
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

Any help would be much appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running testem in `ci` mode? I run it like this:

```
% testem ci --launch PhantomJS
```

Just make sure that the `phantomjs` executable is in your path and all is well.